# Is there a way to create a call script in Twilio without creating many TwiML snippets in separate URLs?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I want to use Twilio to create appointment reminder calls. Each call can have a different call flow with different options for the call recipients to press phone keys, different messages, different languages, etc.

I currently use a service that allows a script to be attached to a call and that script runs on the phone service side so that I don't have to deal with scaling issues when making many thousands of calls at once. I can generate different scripts for each call (or each type of call). I want to switch from that service to Twilio if it's practical.

Since TwiML doesn't have the ability to include logic within a single TwiML file, it seems that in order to do the equivalent would require each call to have many TwiML files. Since I would need each call, or at least each type of call to have different TwiML, I would need to programmatically create each of those files (hosted on Twilio to avoid scaling issues with self-hosting), and somehow manage the many thousands of TwiML files that would remain after each call.

Is there a way to make calls where each call can be attached to a script that incorporates call flow logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Twilio Studio or Twilio Functions to do that and more. You can find more information at the respective links. It is pretty straightforward to get started.

[Studio](https://www.twilio.com/studio) (REST API Trigger)

[Functions](https://www.twilio.com/runtime)

[Function Examples](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/quickstart)

Comment: Thanks for the response. Studio isn't really an option for us since there is no API to create flows and we have hundreds of different flows for various calls going out. We need a way to create them programmatically.

Functions look like they might be a good solution, but I can't say for sure without some examples. Are there examples of Functions that include logic for handling different responses? Specifically, as a simple examples, can a single Function deal with playing a message and doing one thing if '1' is pressed, another thing if '2' is pressed and a third action if no key is pressed?

Comment: Yes to Functions for sure, use the same Twilio Helper library for Node. You can programmatically create Studio Flows using the Flows end-point. You can find more details here - Studio REST API v2 with Flow Publishing - https://www.twilio.com/blog/twilio-releases-summer-2020-recap (Video: https://player.vimeo.com/video/440418210?app_id=122963).